# Failing to deploy Function : "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied but service account has policy granted

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

As a new comer in GCP and Cloud Function, I was following Google Official tutorial to deploy [helloWorld Node.js Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http).

Cloud SDK is at version 366.0.0 and components have been updated.

When building (using cloud_build_local or cloud build), deployment end with error :

```
>ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error":>>{"buildpackId":"","buildpackVersion":"","errorType":"OK","canonicalCode":"OK","errorId":"","errorMessage":""},"stats":[{"buildpackId":"google.utils.archive-source","buildpackVersion":"0.0.1","totalDurationMs":51,"userDurationMs":51},{"buildpackId":"google.nodejs.npm","buildpackVersion":"0.9.0","totalDurationMs":9223,"userDurationMs":9211},{"buildpackId":"google.nodejs.functions-framework","buildpackVersion":"0.9.3","totalDurationMs":2730,"userDurationMs":2679},{"buildpackId":"google.utils.label","buildpackVersion":"0.0.1","totalDurationMs":0,"userDurationMs":0}],"warnings":["*** Improve build performance by generating and committing package-lock.json."]}
```

When looking at the cloud build logs in the console :

```
>Step #1 - "build": ERROR: failed to export: failed to write image to the following tags: [eu.gcr.io/**myproject**/gcf/**europe-west1**/de6f32d4-69e9-4967-a008-6443bd39f1d9:helloHttp_version-1:\
GET https://eu.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3A**myproject**%2Fgcf%2F**europe-west1**%2Fde6f32d4-69e9-4967-a008-6443bd39f1d9%3Apush%2Cpull&scope=repository%3Afn-img%2Fbuildpacks%2Fnodejs16%2Frun%3Apull&service=eu.gcr.io:\
DENIED: Permission "_**artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts**_" denied on resource "projects/**fn-img**/locations/**europe**/repositories/eu.gcr.io" (or it may not exist)]
```

Here are the roles granted to the Cloud Build service account :

```
>ROLE\
roles/appengine.appAdmin\
roles/appengine.deployer\
roles/artifactregistry.reader\
roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder\
roles/cloudbuild.workerPoolUser\
roles/cloudfunctions.developer\
roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypter\
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1\
roles/container.developer\
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser\
roles/run.admin\
roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor\
roles/storage.admin\
```

The configured Docker creds:

```
>  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud"
  }
```

List of activated API in the project :

```
>gcloud services list --enabled
NAME                                 TITLE
aiplatform.googleapis.com            Vertex AI API
apigateway.googleapis.com            API Gateway API
appengine.googleapis.com             App Engine Admin API
artifactregistry.googleapis.com      Artifact Registry API
bigquery.googleapis.com              BigQuery API
bigquerystorage.googleapis.com       BigQuery Storage API
cloudapis.googleapis.com             Google Cloud APIs
cloudbuild.googleapis.com            Cloud Build API
clouddebugger.googleapis.com         Cloud Debugger API
cloudfunctions.googleapis.com        Cloud Functions API
cloudkms.googleapis.com              Cloud Key Management Service (KMS) API
cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com  Cloud Resource Manager API
cloudtrace.googleapis.com            Cloud Trace API
compute.googleapis.com               Compute Engine API
container.googleapis.com             Kubernetes Engine API
containerregistry.googleapis.com     Container Registry API
datastore.googleapis.com             Cloud Datastore API
deploymentmanager.googleapis.com     Cloud Deployment Manager V2 API
dns.googleapis.com                   Cloud DNS API
firebase.googleapis.com              Firebase Management API
iam.googleapis.com                   Identity and Access Management (IAM) API
iamcredentials.googleapis.com        IAM Service Account Credentials API
logging.googleapis.com               Cloud Logging API
monitoring.googleapis.com            Cloud Monitoring API
oslogin.googleapis.com               Cloud OS Login API
pubsub.googleapis.com                Cloud Pub/Sub API
run.googleapis.com                   Cloud Run Admin API
runtimeconfig.googleapis.com         Cloud Runtime Configuration API
secretmanager.googleapis.com         Secret Manager API
servicecontrol.googleapis.com        Service Control API
servicemanagement.googleapis.com     Service Management API
servicenetworking.googleapis.com     Service Networking API
serviceusage.googleapis.com          Service Usage API
source.googleapis.com                Legacy Cloud Source Repositories API
spanner.googleapis.com               Cloud Spanner API
sql-component.googleapis.com         Cloud SQL
sqladmin.googleapis.com              Cloud SQL Admin API
storage-api.googleapis.com           Google Cloud Storage JSON API
storage-component.googleapis.com     Cloud Storage
storage.googleapis.com               Cloud Storage API
vpcaccess.googleapis.com             Serverless VPC Access API`
```

Also, transition from container registry is finalized (even though I never used container registry)

Steps to reproduce: [Following the tutorial :'( :/](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http)

I feel I have been through all the documentation available (I could). I even augmented cloud build service account rights to Storage, Artifacts & Functions admin... I tried with other functions of my own, other regions...

Does any one have any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you share how do you deploy in CLoud Build?

Comment: Hello,

Of course, an important thing I forgot to mention. I deploy following the tutorial as well :

> gcloud functions deploy helloGET --runtime nodejs16 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated

I also tried with alpha and beta components.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you check if you have activated the artifact registry API (in the API -> Catalog menu in the console)?

Comment: Yes it is activated. I updated the question with list of activated services. Also, transition from container registry is finalized (even though I never used container registry).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that tutorial might not be up to date since transition from Container Registry to Artifacts Repository is a must-do.
The solution can be found digging in the documentation [here.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#image_registry_options)

Deploying Cloud Functions with Artifact Repository requires :

- using **alpha or beta SDK** components ;
- **specifying** the target artifact registry via **flag --docker-repository** (setting config artifacts/repository won't suffice) .

As a conclusion, instead of running the command mentionned in the tutorial :

```
gcloud functions deploy helloGET --runtime nodejs16 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

I ran :

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloGET --runtime nodejs16 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --region=europe-west1 __--docker-repository__=projects/myproject/locations/europe-west1/repositories/myrpreviouslycreatedrepo
```

And it worked just fine.